# what is the best jquery selector to get next dropdown combobox in same table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a table where the first column is a radio button and the second column is a dropdown.  i want to have it when i click any of the radio buttons it enables the dropdown that is in the same row.  i know how to disable to dropdown but i can't figure out the right selector

```
 <table>
   <tr>
        <td>[..radio button 1 ..] </td><td> [...dropdown combo 1.  .] </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[..radio button 2..] </td><td> [...dropdown combo 2.  .] </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[..radio button 3..] </td><td> [...dropdown combo 3.  .] </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[..radio button 4..] </td><td> [...dropdown combo 4.  .] </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: What is your html structure ?

Comment: @Khez . . updated with html pseudo code

Comment: From one dropdown context you can do `.parent().next().find('select')` :-?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(':radio').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('td').find('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6d2ET/3/

I think you may be looking to disable when checked and enabled again if not checked, if that's the case, you need to give all your radio inputs the same name attribute and do the following

```
$(':radio').click(function() {
    $('td select').removeAttr('disabled')
    $(this).parent().next().find('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6d2ET/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#radioId').parent().next('td').children('select:eq(0)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").attr("disabled", true);
    $("input").click(function() {
        $("select").attr("disabled", true);
        $(this).closest("tr").find("select").attr("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

### **Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YcSYg/